# Куда можно залить svg изображения?

Tags: svg, хостинг, хостинг-изображений

Есть `SVG` изображение, на какой хостинг его можно залить что бы потом использовать ссылку в `IMG` теге?

Comment: На любой php или свой vds

Comment: Где сайт стоит, туда и заливайте, в чем проблема? Или вы хотите использовать хостинг картинок? Ну попробуйте использовать `svgur.com` - хостинг svg картинок или `Imgur.com`. Или иной другой, в гугл вбейте, там много их.

Comment: @And, спасибо, мне просто нужно будет в след. вопросе SO использовать ссылку на SVG картинку)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, https://svgshare.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://svgur.com/ - Вот сюда можно залить SVG файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Тег `img` может принимать в качестве `src` и `svg` файл
`<img src="kiwi.svg">`

https://jsfiddle.net/agu3Lbtm

Comment: Я понимаю, но мне нужен сервис, что бы я мог залить туда SVG картинку. Я же не могу залить на борд картинку с компьютера( вернее указать путь в src с компьютера)